# Why this LINQ does not update?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Ok This one is driving me nuts! What am i doing wrong here? The Insert operation works but the update does not... Thank you in advance!

```
if (mFromXml.Any()) {
    using (DBDataContext DB = new DBDataContext()) {
        foreach (object m_loopVariable in mFromXml) {
            m = m_loopVariable;
            XSLive mToDb = new XSLive();
            mToDb.Id = m.Id;
            mToDb.Location = m.Location;
            XS.XSLive existingMInDb = (from c in DB.XSLive where c.Id == mToDb.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (existingMInDb != null) {
                existingMInDb = mToDb;
            } else {
                DB.XSLive.InsertOnSubmit(mToDb);
            }
        }
        DB.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Never use `If mFromXml.Count() > 0` to check if a sequence contains elements. That will execute the whole query(if it's not a collection) just to determine the `Count`. Instead use `mFromXml.Any`.

Comment: You say `if (existingMInDb != null) {
                existingMInDb = mToDb;
            }` - so it looks like if you get something, you immediately forget what it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're replacing the existingMInDb object with a new object **by reference**.  The result is that the entire existingMInDb variable now points to mToDb.  The old existingMInDb object, which was tracked by Entity Framework, is gone.

You need to update the properties individually on the existingMInDb object.  You need to change:

```
if (existingMInDb != null) {
    existingMInDb = mToDb;
}
```

To:

```
if (existingMInDb != null) {
    existingMInDbId.Id = mToDb.Id;
    existingMInDbId.Location = mToDb.Location;
}
```